# Regarding Ubuntu and Canon printers

Tags: drivers, updates, printing, canon

In previous versions of Ubuntu the Canon printers have self-loaded and functioned well.  NOT  ANY  LONGER.  How long will it take for Canonical or Ubuntu or ANYONE to issue a "fix" for this supremely annoying shortcoming ?  My specific issue relates to PIXMA MG 2522 all-in-one printers  since I now have 2 of them !  Previous "Ask Ubuntu" notes show a great many - and increasing numbers - of people using Canon printers with Ubuntu having all sorts of problems with versions dating from 18.04 to the current version.  Please - please - somebody pay attention ... and FIX THE PROBLEM ... PLEASE.  Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried googling this (PIXMA MG 2522 Ubuntu drivers)? There are downloadable drivers (debian version) available from Cannon to download for the PIXMA MG 2522 on the cannon europe website.

Comment: Indeed...something like [this](https://canondriversupport.net/download-driver-canon-pixma-mg2522-for-windows-mac-linux/) would do.  But note that it's not up to Canonical, Ubuntu, etc. to "fix" this problem.  It's up to printer manufacturers to open themselves up so that drivers could be made available.  None of Canonical, Microsoft, or Apple could reverse-engineer the interface to a printer without some kind of assistance/permission from the manufacturer.